# How to extract entries from a .txt file using another .txt file as a list

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I would really appreciate some help with this.

I currently have two text files, fileA.txt looks like this:

```
AB307 0.112 0.220 0.341
AB101 0.223 0.474 0.175
AB201 0.101 0.298 0.001
AB209 0.245 0.199 0.222
```

etc.  It is basically a list of sites with a bunch of coordinates after it.

In my second text file, fileB.txt, it is a list of just site names, eg:

```
AB101
AB307
AB209
```

What I would like to do is make a third file that only contains the entries listed on fileB, but has all the details as shown in fileA, ie, with the above entries it would produce fileC.txt which would look like:

```
AB307 0.112 0.220 0.341
AB101 0.223 0.474 0.175
AB209 0.245 0.199 0.222
```

Does anyone know how I can do this, preferably using awk or something similar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

grep is enough for this job:

```
grep -Fwf fileB.txt fileA.txt
```

```
AB307 0.112 0.220 0.341
AB101 0.223 0.474 0.175
AB209 0.245 0.199 0.222
```

Answer (score 2):

This will print the lines of fileA, for which the first words are lines in fileB

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}$1 in a' fileB fileA
AB307 0.112 0.220 0.341
AB101 0.223 0.474 0.175
AB209 0.245 0.199 0.222
```